# Dynamically change toolbar layout in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I created menu_event.xml to customize the toolbar layout of my fragment like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />
```

In order to do it, I used the onCreateOptionsMenu() method in my class and I also set setHasOptionsMenu(true) in my onCreateView() method:

```
public class ListEventActivity extends Fragment {

    public ListEventActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_event, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_event, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

But even this way it doesn't change the toolbar layout and the action overflow item remains (instead it adds "settings" and "search" to its items...

Any ideas about how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `invalidateOptionsMenu` (or `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` in case you are using AppCompat) method to refresh the ActionBar.

Comment: I'm using it but it doens't add the icon to my action bar, it only add items to the overflow menu..

Answer (score 0):

Just add a regular XML layout file and use findViewById to find the view and manipulate it to your heart's desire. You can then set your click handlers etc to handle button click

Comment: Minimal code to demonstrate what you suggest would be helpful.